# Magento 2: error in developer mode: help debugging

Tags: magento2, debug

when i put Magento 2 in developer mode i get this error, can you help me debugging? Thanks

```
                1 exception(s):
            Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'remove': This element is not expected.
            Line: 789


            Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'remove': This element is not expected.
            Line: 789

            #0 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
            #1 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/home/r2gutenb/...', '%message%\nLine:...')
            #2 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
            #3 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
            #4 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
            #5 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
            #6 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
            #7 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<!--\r\n    <refe...')
            #8 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
            #9 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
            #10 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
            #11 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
            #12 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
            #13 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
            #14 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
            #15 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'home')
            #16 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
            #17 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
            #18 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #19 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
            #20 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #21 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
            #22 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #23 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #24 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
            #25 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #26 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #27 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #28 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #29 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #30 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
            #31 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #32 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
            #33 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/index.php(46): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
            #34 {main}
```

log:

> [2018-08-01 12:14:24] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout:
>   LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_10da09d9bc893ff7f794d52e619ffffd13 and handles
>   default, cms_index_index, cms_page_view, cms_index_index_id_home,
>   weltpixel_googlecards_remove_opengraph,
>   weltpixel_googlecards_remove_schema: Please correct the XML data and
>   try again. Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Line: 789

Comment: i know it's a xml layout problem but i can't understand wich one

Comment: I can see reference to "page_content_heading" so maybe there's a remove node in the layout XML for a block called page_content_heading, which is part of the Magento_Cms package. Be sure to check whether it's caused by the Weltpixel extensions too.

Comment: tried to disable Weltpixel, the error isn't here.

Comment: i am trying to find cms_index_index_id_home

Comment: i can't find it

Comment: If you're using Mac OSX or a Linux distribution, you can try running `grep -r '<remove '  /path/to/magento/root` which should return all of the instances for a <remove> xml node. From there you may be able to narrow it down a bit more. If you're on Windows I'm not sure of the actual command so you may need to find an alternative to `grep`

Comment: ok i've done, but now other exceptions are coming. there is no way to turn of this? i remove error reporting from all the files i can find, but still reporting

Comment: If the next exception has appeared now, then you're likely on a good track. Rather than hiding errors you should be aiming to resolve them, as is the purpose of developer mode and its error reporting.

Comment: @Rhys-SproutDesk yeah this is what i am doing! thank you :)

Comment: The error is down to welt pixel rich snippets you need to modify the frontend layouts and remove         <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
 from both so all you are left with is  <body>            <referenceBlock name="opengraph.general" remove="true" /></body>

Answer (score 0):

As @Rhys has pointed out,

> I can see reference to "page_content_heading" so maybe there's a
>   remove node in the layout XML for a block called page_content_heading,
>   which is part of the Magento_Cms package. Be sure to check whether
>   it's caused by the Weltpixel extensions too.

The "remove" action is allowed in layout xml files, but it is not allowed in the backend.

You say that you are searching for `cms_index_index_id_home`, which is a layout handle that is generated for the homepage only.

So, in the backend, go to *Content > Pages*, open your homepage and see if there is anything written in the *Design -> Layout-XML* textarea. I assume that there is a "remove" directive.

If not, check every CMS block that appears on the homepage. Same field, same expected content of layout xml update field.